# Keeping to Google API quotas with client-side applications

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, client-side, quota

Google APIs can have usage limits, both on a per-user and a per-application basis. For example, the [GMail API free tier](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota) is limited to a billion daily quota units across all users of your application.

This works for well-designed server-side applications, which can centrally ensure they obey these usage limits. However, I’m not sure how this is supposed to work for client-side apps. As [Google’s documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) says,

> Installed apps are distributed to individual devices, and it is assumed that these apps cannot keep secrets.

These apps are still supposed to use a `client_secret` and credentials, but these are assumed to not be confidential despite the name. However, just saying they aren’t secret doesn’t prevent abuse; a user of the app can take the credentials file and use it for a different purpose, perhaps one that uses the APIs more. What can an application developer do to prevent people doing this from burning through all the available quota?

Edit for clarification:

The use case that prompted this is a purely desktop app that doesn’t connect to any service except GMail (see https://github.com/mbrt/gmailctl/issues/48). If it weren’t for a global quota for all users of the app, there would be no reason to worry about individual users at all; they don’t connect to any service except GMail itself.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a server app (a Cloud Function would work) which holds the secrets. Clients call your endpoint with some form of identifier and you return an Access Token. If your users have a browser, they can auth each time; if not you would need to request a Refresh Token which you store and use that to generate an AT.

Comment: How would that actually help? The client would still need to call the new endpoint for an access token, and somebody else could call the endpoint the same way. It could let you IP block abusive clients, I suppose?

Comment: It means your app can control authentication.

Comment: But will you actually have enough information to control it with? AFAICT the only extra information you have to make a decision with which is at all difficult to spoof is client IP address.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are now asking. You seem to be asking me how your app should authenticate your users. That's kinda down to you.

Comment: @Daniel H, I think you should refer the source ( https://github.com/mbrt/gmailctl/issues/48 ) to clarify your intent of this question.

Comment: @benok Good idea. I think the confusion between pinoyyid and myself was that otherwise there *is* no authentication of users. It’s a desktop app designed to *just* access GMail, not any other service; there’s no reason to keep track of the users at all except for burning global quota.